# Register New user - Missing Constructor Message

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

**[This question does NOT already have an answer]**

This is related to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164180/sql-server-express-connection-to-mdf-file), to which I have been unable to find a solution. I simply failed to get LocalDb to work with an existing project. So, I decided to create a blank database in SSMS and update the Web.config file for that.

I have also tried using solutions to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965210/constructor-on-type-system-data-entity-infrastructure-sqlconnectionfactory-not) question, but nothing worked.

I am getting the following error when trying to register a new user:

> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory' not
>   found.

I updated my Entity Framework version from 6.1.3 to 6.2.0 and still the same error. First time I tried this, it hosed the existing MDF database file from the App_Data folder. I got various DB permissions errors along the way.

My Web.config:

```
        <connectionStrings>
            <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
            <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=Development;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       </connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor on type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965210/constructor-on-type-system-data-entity-infrastructure-sqlconnectionfactory-not)

Comment: They both point to the same question and I tried that before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past this error by adding a parameters entry for the entityframework section of my Web.config as follows:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

This lead me to solving the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164180/sql-server-express-connection-to-mdf-file), and I have provided an answer there also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type = "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />       
</entityFramework>
```

or

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
 </entityFramework>
```

or

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

I have removed

```
<providers>    
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

and changed

Comment: The first one leads to this: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)